# Como inverter os valores da diagonal principal de uma matriz 5x5?

Tags: java, matriz

Exemplo entrada:

> **1** 3 6 8 7
>   3 **7** 8 0 3
>   2 4 **3** 6 7
>   8 9 1 **3** 5
>   5 6 7 8 **5**

Exemplo saída:

> **5** 3 6 8 7
>   3 **3** 8 9 3
>   2 4 **3** 6 7
>   8 0 1 **7** 5
>   5 6 7 8 **1**

Tenho até agora isso:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int [][] Matriz = new int [5][5];
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++ ){ 
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){ 
        System.out.println("introduce un valor para la posicion "+ i +", "+ j);
        try{ 
            Matriz[i][j]= Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()); 
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
} 
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++ ){
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        System.out.print(Matriz[i][j]+" ");
    } 
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare um array para guardar a diagonal:

```
int [] diagonal = new int[5];
```

Entre os "for" de entrada e os de saída introduza este código:

```
//Guarda diagonal
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++ ){
    diagonal[i] = Matriz[i][i];
}
//Repõe a diagonal na direção inversa
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++ ){
    Matriz[i][i] = diagonal[4-i];
}
```

Veja no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/17jQk3)

Outra forma mais rápida se necessitar só do *output*.
Substitua o "for" de saída por este:

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++ ){
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
        if(j==i){
            System.out.print(Matriz[4-i][4-j]+" ");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(Matriz[i][j]+" ");
        }
    } 
    System.out.println();
}
```

Veja no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/eI4cGq)

Comment: Acho que teria que salvar o valor atual numa variável temporária para substituir "do outro lado"

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo!

Answer (score 2):

Eu prefiro percorrer só uma vez da seguinte forma:

```
int TAMANHO_MATRIZ = 5;

for(int i = 0; i<TAMANHO_MATRIZ/2; i++ ){
    int aux = Matriz[i][i]
    Matriz[i][i] = Matriz[TAMANHO_MATRIZ-i-1][TAMANHO_MATRIZ-i-1];
    Matriz[TAMANHO_MATRIZ-i-1][TAMANHO_MATRIZ-i-1] = aux;
}
```

Comment: Boa opção, obrigado.